# FQL returns much less results than GRAPH

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, feed

I am trying to get the user's feed. I have both user_status and read_stream permissions.
When I do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

I get tons of results.

But when I do an FQL of:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message,description FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
```

I get 4(!) results. According to Facebook's [Stream documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/):

> source_id int The ID of the user, page, group, or event whose wall the post is on

Aren't the results supposed to be equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **LIMIT 50** to the end of your FQL. It worked for me. The *available* stories are the same for FQL and graph.facebook.com (the greater of 30 days ago or 50 stories), however the *quantity* of stories returned by default seem to be different for reasons I don't know yet.

Comment: This does return more results. The question is **WHY**? I made [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837531/unexpected-behavior-when-using-fql), no answer yet