# How to get the privacy values with FQL query from stream table entries using a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, privacy

I would like to know the privacy values (CUSTOM, ALL_FRIENDS, etc.) of the stream entries from a Facebook application, but the result does not contain privacy field values for all of the returned entries.

The application requests the following permissions: read_stream, export_stream, user_friends.

The query used by the application:

```
SELECT post_id, attachment, description, privacy 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() 
ORDER BY updated_time DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

The privacy part of the result looks like this for most of the entries (there are some which have privacy values):

```
...
"privacy": {
    "value": ""
}
...
```

If I filter for the value of the privacy field then it seems that only shared links have privacy values:

```
SELECT post_id, attachment, description, privacy 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() AND privacy.value != "" 
ORDER BY updated_time DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

I have already tried to run the query with all Facebook permissions available, the result was the same, no privacy values from the application.

But if I run the query in the Graph API Explorer with the same permissions, then I get the correct privacy values for all kinds of entries:

```
"privacy": {
    "description": "Public", 
    "value": "EVERYONE", 
    "friends": "", 
    "networks": "", 
    "allow": "", 
    "deny": ""
}
```

The fql query without any filters:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2Cattachment%2C%20description%2C%20privacy%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20%3D%20me()%20ORDER%20BY%20updated_time%20DESC%20%20LIMIT%2020

The fql query with privacy filter (privacy.value != ""):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2Cupdated_time%2C%20attachment%2C%20type%2C%20description%2C%20privacy%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20%3D%20me()%20AND%20privacy.value!%3D%22%22%20ORDER%20BY%20privacy.value%20DESC%20%20LIMIT%2020

These are the two apps' settings, although they look identical:

Graph API Explorer settings
[image: Graph API Explorer settings]
MyAppDev facebook app settings
[image: MyAppDev facebook app settings]

Any ideas how I can get the correct privacy values using a Facebook application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works in the Graph API Explorer and doesn't in your app, something is wrong in your app. In my opinion, you most probably didn't successfully requested the permissions inside your app.

---

In your [app settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), can you see the permissions you requested, just like on the picture?

[image: App permissions]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the original question with images of the apps' settings which seem to be identical, so the rights seem to be ok.

Comment: Humm ok, thank you for checking. Then you use a similar token. I think you don't have any difference in the results between the Graph Explorer and your own app and that you didn't correctly read into the results. It **can't** be different. You were using two queries. Just use the same on both site and please show us the results. I guess the origin of your question is the lack of privacy information for some posts, but that's normal in the case of posts that your friends posted (ant not you) and tagged you in for example, because privacy settings can only be seen by the current session user.

Comment: There were multiple problems:
1. I didn't know that the `LIMIT` clause of FQL works in a strange way explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837531/unexpected-behavior-when-using-fql/11952946#11952946)
2. The Graph API Explorer returned 20 entries created by the user and all had privacy values.
3. The app returned 20 entries as well but most of them were not created by the user and that's why they didn't have privacy values.

Increasing the `LIMIT` to 10000 and filtering for records that have privacy values seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Great! Glad you figured that out.